# Postgresql: How to insert row value in the output even if it is not present in column

Tags: sql, postgresql

let table name "box" the box will have

```
1. pen
2. pencil
3. eraser
4. sharpener
5. scale
```

but may SQL table looks like this,

```
s no.___    item____  quantity

 1 _____       pen_____     2

 2 ____      pencil____   3

 3____      eraser____    5
```

i need a query, which gives me the following output

```
item______      quantity

pen ______          2

pencil ____       3

eraser ____       5

sharpener__     0

scale   ____      0
```

This is the query i am using right now

select CASE disease_confirmed 
when 'Forward to EMMINENT Cardiologist' then 'Repeat ECG Within 10 Minutes'
when 'Yes' then 'Yes'
when 'No' then 'No'
when 'Re-take ECG' then 'Re-take ECG'
when 'Reassign to 1 Cardiologist' then 'Reassign to 1 Cardiologist'
when 'Reassign to 2 Cardiologists' then 'Reassign to 2 Cardiologists'
when 'Reassign to 3 Cardiologists' then 'Reassign to 3 Cardiologists'

END AS disease_confirmed,

count(disease_confirmed) from immi_referral_tb where created_date>= '2015-11-01 00:00'::timestamp AND created_date<= '2015-11-30 23:59'::timestamp group by disease_confirmed 
union all
SELECT 'Total',count(disease_confirmed)
from immi_referral_tb where created_date>= '2015-11-01 00:00'::timestamp AND created_date<= '2015-11-30 23:59'::timestamp;

output:

[click here for output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7nz9.jpg)

so i need the following values under "disease confirmed column" 
Re-take ECG
Yes
Reassign to 3 Cardiologists
Repeat ECG
Reassign to 1 Cardiologist
No
Reassign to 2 Cardiologists

but according to my query i have 1 month time period, so some of the above values are not present in the column for that time period.

so, need those all values in the output like null '0' if there are not present in the column.

Comment: This is completly unclear. Post your table schema and sample of your table data with the desired output.

Comment: Where do you contain all the items names?(without the quantity only the names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create another table with the expected items and left join on it:

```
CREATE TABLE expected (item VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO expected
VALUES ('pen'), ('pencil'), ('eraser'), ('sharpener'), ('scale');

SELECT    e.item, COALESCE(b.quantity, 0)
FROM      expected e
LEFT JOIN box b ON e.item = b.item
```

If you don't want to create another table you could use a query that selects hard-coded literals instead:

```
SELECT    e.item, COALESCE(b.quantity, 0)
FROM      (SELECT 'pen' AS item
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'pencil'
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'eraser'
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'sharpener'
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'scale') e
LEFT JOIN box b ON e.item = b.item
```

Comment: You don't actually need the `create table`. You could use a cte or a derived table directly with the `values` clause from the insert

Comment: I have one more question, can i use 'count' in this statement like
""SELECT    e.item, COALESCE(b.count(item), 0)""  in the first line ??

i tried like that but it is showing some ambigious error. please help .

Comment: @saivenkatavinaypasupuleti can you share the exact SQL you're using and the error's text?

Comment: SELECT    e.disease_confirmed, COALESCE(b.count(disease_confirmed), 0)
FROM      (SELECT 'Yes' AS disease_confirmed UNION ALL
SELECT 'No' UNION ALL SELECT 'Forward to EMMINENT Cardiologist' UNION ALL SELECT 'Re-take ECG' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Reassign to 1 Cardiologist' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Reassign to 2 Cardiologists' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Reassign to 3 Cardiologists') e
LEFT JOIN immi_referral_tb b ON e.disease_confirmed = b.disease_confirmed
ERROR:  column reference "disease_confirmed" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT    e.disease_confirmed, COALESCE(b.count(disease_conf...
SQL state: 42702 Character: 49

Comment: sorry for confusing comment, it is not allowing more characters